# Why is onResourceReceived invoked twice by PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Suppose I've got a `phantomJS` script like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create()

page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    console.log('requested: ' + req.url);
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
   console.log('received: ' + res.url);
};

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/hello.html'

page.open(url, function (status) {
  console.log(page.content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

When I run the script `requested` appears in the log just once but `received` appears *twice*. Could you explain why `received` appears twice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources can be potentially very large. If they are, you will notice a time difference between the "same" two events. That's because the first is the *start* of the resource reception and the next is the *end*. You can check for the stage by checking `response.stage`.

Reference: [`page.onResourceReceived`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html)

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty sure the resource is not large though.

Comment: There are still two stages, regardless how big the resource is. The "big resource" example should only give you an idea of when having two stages makes sense.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I am logging the stage and see `start` and `end` now.